# unable to change ownership of files

Tags: 12.04, mount, permissions, ntfs

I am working out on an answer as given here 
https://superuser.com/a/623998/63915
I copied the windowsios to a usb drive

```
mount -t o loop win.iso /media/usb
```

but I see permissions problem all the files are owned by `root:root`
and when I try to do do

```
sudo chown -R user:user /media/usb/
```

there is no change in permissions in files of USB 
I see following

```
 ls -l
total 3250
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     110 Oct  9 17:11 autorun.inf
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Oct  9 17:11 docs
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40960 Oct  9 17:35 grub
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     313 Oct  9 17:25 grub.cfg
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1208320 Oct  9 17:13 i386
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45124 Oct  9 17:14 ntdetect.com
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3204 Oct  9 17:13 readme.htm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  260288 Oct  9 17:14 RUFUSLDR
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1310720 Oct  9 17:13 setup.exe
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Oct  9 17:13 support
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  449797 Oct  9 17:16 txtsetup.sif
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Oct  9 17:13 valueadd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct  9 17:13 win51
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct  9 17:13 win51ip
```

what went wrong here?

Comment: What is the output of `df -T` command?

Comment: I see my usb here /dev/sdb1      fuseblk    3914748   562760   3351988  15% /media/3AE27070E27031ED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chown` fails because the mounted file system is `fuseblk`. So you are trying to write meta data to a file system which the file system does not support (cannot store). You can only change permissions and ownership on a Unix filesystem like  `ext3` or `ext4`.

If you want that mounted point with ownership applied to a specific user/group, specify at the mount time:

```
mount -o uid=username,gid=groupname /dev/sdb1 /path/to/mount
```

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73955/unable-to-change-permissions-of-file-system-root

Comment: well I am not mounting that usb,when I insert USB to my laptop ubuntu automatically does that, i think this default behaviour is caused due to gnome-mount (udisks) working in backend is causing problems,because when I unmount the USB from nautilus window `sudo fdisk -l` does not show any kind of USB stick i.e. /dev/sdb1 should come here

Comment: @RegisteredUser Whatever you mount, I suspect that what you mount doesn't have a Unix filesystem format like ext3 or ext4. So, use  `mount` with `-o uid=username,gid=groupname` option if you want that mounted point with ownership applied to a specific user/group.